# Python 3 - Array in Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I just started learning python3 about a week and a half ago. Now the books covers lists, tuples and directory. I hope my question is not to dumb but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Say, I have a list of names with the ages of the people:

```
Klaus, 34
Doris, 20
Mark, 44
Tina, 19
```

What I would like to have (and what I could do in php :-) ) is a multidimensional array like

```
1st array(name=Klaus, age=34), 
2nd array(name=Doris, age=20), 
3rd array(name=Mark, age=44), 
4th array(name=Tina, age=19)
```

in php it would look like:

```
$multiarray = array(array(name =>"Peter", age=>34),
                    array(name=>"Doris",age=>20),
                    array(name=>"Mark",age=>44),
                    array(name=>"Tina", age=>19));
```

how do I do this in python3?

Again sorry for a probably dumb question :-)

Mark

Comment: Why not use just one dictionary? `{'Peter': 34, 'Doris': 20, ...}`

Comment: I would like to do something like this:

    length = len(multiarray)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        print("{name} is {age} years old".format(multiarray[i]["name"], multiarray[i]["age"]))
        i += 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, this would probably be a `list` of `dict`ionaries:

```
multiarray = [{"name": "Peter", "age": 34}, ...]
```

e.g. Peter's age would be

```
multiarray[0]["age"]
```

---

Having just spotted your comment, note that you can do

```
for person in multiarray:
    print("{0[name]} is {0[age]} years old.".format(person))
```

Manually incrementing an index `i` is not very Pythonic: you can either:

1. Iterate through the items directly (`for item in lst`);
2. Use `enumerate` to get the item and index (`for index, item in enumerate(lst)`); or
3. Use `range` to generate the indices (`for index in range(len(lst))`).

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. Lists, Tuples and Dictionaries confuse me a little bit - Hope this will get better :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your comment on the question

Comment: you're a goldmine :) Thanks for helping me out. Seems I have to get another book which goes into more details about all the list, tupels and dictionary stuff

Comment: I found another soulution:

`persons = {"Dieter":34, "Doris":20, "Petra":29, "Mark":24}
print(persons)`

`for name, age in persons.items():
    print("{0} ist {1} Jahre alt".format(name, age))`

This works perfect for me :-)

Comment: Yes, that will work fine if you only have one parameter per person. You could also use a dictionary of dictionaries: {'Mark':{'age': 24}, ...}` allowing you to have multiple parameters (e.g. 'occupation', 'address', ...) per person, or even create a custom `Person` class allowing the addition of specific functions to a person.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for:

`persons = {"Dieter":{'age':34,'city':'Berlin'}, "Doris":{'age':20,'city':'München'},"Petra":{'age':29, 'city':'Hamburg'}, 'Mark':{'age':24, 'city':'New York'}}
for key in persons.keys():
    print("{0} wohnt in {1} und ist {2} Jahre alt".format(key, persons[key]['city'],persons[key]['age']))`

Now I am happy :-)

Comment: Again, you can simplify: `for name in persons: print("{0} wohnt in {1[city]} und ist {1[age]} Jahre alt".format(name, persons[name]))`